# i want to remove the coordinates and show the information about the place data

Tags: javascript, openlayers

## i want to remove the coordinates and show the information about the place data

AsslamOAlikum. Hi i create openlayer map with the help of geoserver. My map application in base on javascript and openlayers (OSM, WMS). In my application i use multiple layers, mouse handling & positioning and popup function. But i want to some changing in my popup function. In my popup function when i click the mouse button then show the coordinates of 'E,W,Degree' ETC. I want to change to coordinate replace into the get featured information about the place. HERE is my  code......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Overlay</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #marker {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #088;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #0FF;
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
      #vienna {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
      }
      .popover-content {
        min-width: 180px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div style="display: none;">
      <!-- Popup -->
      <div id="popup" title="Welcome to OpenLayers"></div>
    </div>

     <div id="nodelist">
        <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
    </div>
    <div id="mouse-position"></div>
    <form>
      <label>Projection </label>
      <select id="projection">
        <option value="EPSG:4326">EPSG:4326</option>
      </select>
      <label>Precision </label>
      <input id="precision" type="number" min="0" max="12" value="4"/>
    </form>

    <script>

        //MOUSE HANDLING
         var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });



        var LonLat = [69.3451, 30.3753];
    var pos = ol.proj.fromLonLat(LonLat);

      var layer =[ 
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          //extent: [68.107725, 23.744288, 73.622861, 36.878836],
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://gulraiz-pc:8080/geoserver/test/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'test:pak_ad3_gaul_ply_15072010', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver'

          })
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          //extent: [68.107725, 23.744288, 73.622861, 36.878836],
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://gulraiz-pc:8080/geoserver/test/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': '  test:longlist', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver'

          })
        })
    ];
      var map = new ol.Map({
          controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
//            collapsible: false
          })
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        layers: layer,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: pos,
          zoom: 5
        })
      });



      // Popup showing the position the user clicked
      var popup = new ol.Overlay({
        element: document.getElementById('popup')
      });
      map.addOverlay(popup);



      map.on('click', function(evt) {
        var element = popup.getElement();
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(
            coordinate, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:4326'));

        $(element).popover('destroy');
        popup.setPosition(coordinate);
        // the keys are quoted to prevent renaming in ADVANCED mode.
        $(element).popover({
          'placement': 'top',
          'animation': false,
          'html': true,
          'content': '<p>The location you clicked was:</p><code>' + hdms + '</code>'
        });
        $(element).popover('show');
      });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: coordinates are show but i want information in the format of table. in which table like this link
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand what you are asking for. Going to assume that you want the coordinates of the feature and not the click.

`forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, (f) => {
    coordinate = f.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
}`

Comment: coordinates are show but i want information in the format of table. in which table like this link
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html

Comment: coordinates are working but i need information in table i send above link
please watch link and resolve my problem.
i try but its throw exception.

Comment: No. Either do exactly what that example does and use a WMS info url or extract  the info from the feature and build a table.

`var title = f.get('TITLE'); 
 var html = '<table><th>Title</th><tr><td>' + title + '</td></tr></table>';
`